# Haskell Cabal - network-simple-0.4.3 installation issues

Tags: haskell

Had the issue Cabal showed errors before, but what I'd like to know: is there really something wrong with the package or is my installation fubar again. Can one of you help me out here?

```
MacBook-2:hs_level_0 administrator$ cabal install network-simple
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring safe-exceptions-0.1.7.0...
Building safe-exceptions-0.1.7.0...
Failed to install safe-exceptions-0.1.7.0
Build log ( /Users/administrator/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.4.3/safe-exceptions-0.1.7.0-CwMBtoBr1y8CsvtCCUeprP.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/var/folders/81/50s00bl11pv7fn8dw4n0w03m0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-3554/safe-exceptions-0.1.7.0'
Configuring safe-exceptions-0.1.7.0...
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
Preprocessing library for safe-exceptions-0.1.7.0..
Building library for safe-exceptions-0.1.7.0..
[1 of 1] Compiling Control.Exception.Safe ( src/Control/Exception/Safe.hs, dist/build/Control/Exception/Safe.o )

src/Control/Exception/Safe.hs:94:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Control.Monad.Catch’
    There are files missing in the ‘exceptions-0.10.0’ package,
    try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
94 | import qualified Control.Monad.Catch as C
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

src/Control/Exception/Safe.hs:95:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Control.Monad.Catch’
    There are files missing in the ‘exceptions-0.10.0’ package,
    try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
95 | import Control.Monad.Catch (Handler (..))
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cabal: Leaving directory '/var/folders/81/50s00bl11pv7fn8dw4n0w03m0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-3554/safe-exceptions-0.1.7.0'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
network-simple-0.4.3-Coj7l4Fv6BIGNsyIlRxnky depends on network-simple-0.4.3
which failed to install.
safe-exceptions-0.1.7.0-CwMBtoBr1y8CsvtCCUeprP failed during the building
phase. The except
```

ion was:
ExitFailure 1

Comment: Presumably it is your installation, though it is hard to make a more precise diagnostic. You might find [this discussion](https://github.com/goldfirere/singletons/issues/147) relevant.

Comment: @duplode had the same feeling. Last time nuked all of it, reinstalled and it was stable again for 2 weeks... Anyway think I can close it and just start over